# Forcing fonts to be embedded in LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts

I have compiled a huge document with LuaLaTeX - I've tried stripping it down to a MWE but cannot get the behaviour to repeat.

The issue is that the document contains un-embedded fonts, and to submit my PhD thesis to my university I need all fonts to be embedded.

I have tried doing embedding fonts after compiling in Acrobat Pro, but lots of characters break when you do this.

So I have to do it in LaTeX - but I can't work out how to solve this. I've heard rumour of editing pdftex.map in some folder like /users//library/texlive etc etc but I can't find it, and don't know what to edit.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

EDIT: I solved the problem through a lot of trial and error and wanted to describe how here in case someone else stumbles on this question. In short, I had pdf figures generated in R that did not contain embedded fonts. I started an Adobe Acrobat trial (free) so I could use the pro features. I then saved all figures as pdf/a. This embedded the fonts without any degradation or significant alterations (I tried other methods that stopped the graphs being lossless - but this method worked a treat).

One wrinkle was a few figures for which Adobe broke when trying to save as pdf/a. For these, I used the embedFonts() function in R - embedFonts(filename, new_filename) - this took the original pdf graphs and embedded the fonts. I still had to do the conversion to pdf/a for some reason in Adobe, but the combination of steps for the problem graphs.

The combination of these two approaches allowed me to upload my thesis to the online directory. Hope this helps someone else who runs into this issue.

Comment: well without know which font is not embedded it is quite difficult to help you. But normally I would expect that the problem is from embedded pictures, and editing the pdftex.map won't help here.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer - it was indeed the pictures, see the EDIT where I show how I deal with the various issues.

Comment: @mr_phd Would you like to add your edit as a separate answer as long as the question hasn't been closed?